# LIBLINEAR is very sensitive to C parameter

Tags: libsvm

I'm getting different results from LIBLINEAR and it's wrapper in scikit-learn for python. The former is very sensitive to the C parameter (the quality in my case is very low at the default setting C=1 and sharply increases while increasing C), which is contrary to what is stated in the docs and to the scikit-learn wrapper behaviour. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar to what scikit-learn docs says but the behaviour you are describing is the expected one.

When you talk about "Quality" I am guessing you are referring to the training error and the performance error. As you probably are aware of, the parameter C is the penalty cost that the model "pays" for each misclassification. In that sense, one can think that with a higher C you would tell the algorithm to be as picky as possible and adjust as best to the data as it can given the parameters provided, hence high C tends to be closer to over fitting the training set.

So, is that a good thing? Well it depends, in general if you increase the C value too much then you might suffer of over fitting and do it very poorly with the general performance error. However, the C value often varies with your data and how /(if you) performed the normalization on it.I have always had to change to default value of C as it never had worked for me. Sometimes by using C=10, some other times by using C=100. A good way to find this is using cross validation to search for a value that would work with your dataset.

Comment: I'm asking why the results could be different in LIBLINEAR and scikit-learn, which uses LIBLINEAR internally. LIBLINEAR docs say that the quality should be pretty stable and C should not affect it too much. And is it this way with scikit-learn, but not with the LIBLINEAR itself.

Comment: @lizarisk Can you provide the part of the documentation where that is stated? I only could find this extract for L1 L2 regularized logistic regression "C : float, optional (default=1.0)



Specifies the strength of the regularization. The smaller it is the bigger is the regularization
" (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html ) which is essentially what I said. Also can you provide a bit of detail about what exactly are you doing? The parameters that you are using? Etc...

Comment: It's in the end of LIBLINEAR paper, section L5: "Solvers in LIBLINEAR is not very sensitive to C. Once C is larger than certain value, the obtained models have similar performances. A theoretical proof of this kind of results is in Theorem 3 of Keerthi and Lin (2003)."

Comment: @lizarisk Well, that's true "once is larger than a certain value" but that value is usually far from C=1 and it is normal to the model to be sensible to changes on C until you reach that threshold. What intrigues me is that you report different results from the wrapper and the original implementation which should be at the very least close. Can you please tell us what are you using in both sides (liblinear and scikit-learn)? there is a chance that because the parameters both models are not really equivalent.

Comment: C=1 is large enough for scikit-learn. I'm using LinearSVC with default parameters in scikit-learn and LIBLINEAR with similar parameters.